# How to make sure my array structure is the same in both Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Am calling a .mm (objective-c / c++) class method from my swift viewController via linked headers.They are successfully linked. However, I am struggling to pass correct data types that match as arguments. 
Here is where I call the function in swift

```
OpenCVWrapper.thefunc(array1, otherstuff);
```

..`.array1` is of type `[[Int]]`

and here is the definition in objective-c

```
+(NSString*) thefunc: (int[][2])array1 otherstuff(int)other{
```

but i get the error

```
Cannot convert value of type '[[Int]]' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablepointer<(Int32)(Int32)>!'
```

As discussed in another similar question i posted, I need to make sure swift array1 is in fact of type [(Int32, Int32)]. Now, no errors get thrown.

BUT, when I dry run the Objective-C method, the array1 only shows with 2 values (after break point). Where as in Swift i pass through 9 (of 2), which is what I want.

My question is, **how can I confirm my array in objective-c will be the same structure to the one in swift?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are relying on the debugger to show you the values passed in as array1.  To verify programmatically that correct values are passed, you can do the following in `thefunc()`:

```
+(NSString*) thefunc : (int[][2])array1 {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        printf("Tuple %d is: %d, %d\n", i, array1[i][0], array1[i][1]);
    ...
}
```

9 is the number of 2-int tuples you passed.  This count should probably be passed as one of the things in `otherstuff`, unless it is always the same.

BTW, you should probably pass array1 as in-out in Swift (note the `&`):

```
OpenCVWrapper.thefunc(&array1,...)
```

Comment: turns out debugger was not showing me all values - so yes your right cheers.